# Adding inline reply actions

Tags: android-notifications

Here is code to generate inline notification everything is working fine but I don't want to show MessageReply.class.

> Current problem: A white screen is appear as pending intent is called
>   while sending message.
>
> Required result: No such white screen work same like whatsapp inline
>   notification.

```
  void buildNotification(String messageValue) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Test.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        intent.putExtra(Consts.EXTRA_MESSAGE, messageValue);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle(Consts.GCM_NOTIFICATION)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(messageValue))
                .setContentText(messageValue)
                .addAction(buildReplyFromNotification(extras));

        Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }


    private NotificationCompat.Action buildReplyFromNotification(Bundle data) {
        String replyLabel = getResources().getString(R.string.reply_label);
        RemoteInput remoteInput = new RemoteInput.Builder(KEY_TEXT_REPLY).setLabel(replyLabel).build();
        // Create the reply action and add the remote input.
        return new NotificationCompat
                .Action
                .Builder(R.drawable.ic_send, getString(R.string.reply_label), buildReplyPendingIntent(data))
                .addRemoteInput(remoteInput)
                .build();
    }

    private PendingIntent buildReplyPendingIntent(Bundle messageValue) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MessageReply.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        intent.putExtra(Consts.EXTRA_DIALOG_ID, messageValue.getString("dialog_id"));
        return PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use theme for that activity `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`